# Initialize object with PROGMEM constants

Tags: progmem

I have a class which has a `const char *` property:

```cpp
    class A
    {
    public:
        const PROGMEM char* text;
    };

    void setup()
    {
        // A a{"Hello World!"};
        // A a{PSTR("Hello World!")};

        A a;
        a.text = PSTR("Hello World!");

        Serial.begin(9600);
        delay(30);
        Serial.println(a.text);
    }

    void loop()
    {
    }
```

I’d like to spare some RAM using `PROGMEM`.

How to initialize `a` object then?

Obviously, it can’t be like this:

```cpp
    A a{PSTR("Hello World!")};
```

This will do:

```cpp
    A a;
    a.text = PSTR("Hello World!");
```

However, I need to pass string to the constructor.

Comment: does `a.text = F("Hello World!");` do what you want?

Comment: @dandavis, it does not. you've missed that a.text is not `const __FlashStringHelper*` - it's `const char*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a shame that gcc only supports the `__flash` qualifier in C mode,
not in C++, so we have to use `PROGMEM` instead. Unlike `__flash`, which
qualifies a variable just like `const`, the `PROGMEM` attribute only has
effect when allocating room for a variable. Once the allocation is done,
the compiler forgets about the attribute. In particular, a declaration
such as

```cpp
const PROGMEM char* text;
```

does not allocate flash space, so it generates the warning

```
warning: ‘__progmem__’ attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
     const PROGMEM char* text;
                         ^
```

You can thus forget the attribute when declaring a pointer, as there is
no such thing as a “pointer to `PROGMEM`”. You just use a `const char *`
instead.

Now, the second issue is that, as far as `Serial.println()` is
concerned, the pointer above is a plain `const char *`, so it will
interpret it as an address in RAM, and print garbage. If you want
`Serial.println()` to know you are giving it an address in flash, you
should provide it with a `const __FlashStringHelper*` pointer.

Here is the solution I propose. Tested on an Uno-compatible board:

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    A(const char* s)
        : text(reinterpret_cast<const __FlashStringHelper *>(s)) {}
    const __FlashStringHelper* text;
};

void setup()
{
    A a{PSTR("Hello World!")};
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println(a.text);
}

void loop(){}
```

---

**Edit**: After seeing the last version of Juraj’s answer, I must say
that I agree with him. Since we are using the Arduino API, it makes more
sense for the constructor to take a `const __FlashStringHelper*`, and
for the caller to use the `F()` macro.

Comment: your solution works fine! thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

`const char* text;` is a pointer to constant not a constant pointer (`char * const text` is a constant pointer). So you can assign a pointer to a constant char array to `const char* text;` even a pointer to an array in PROGMEM.

The compiler doesn't know the difference between a PROGMEM pointer and a pointer in SRAM. It is on you to work in code with a pointer to PROGMEM the right way.

so remove PROGMEM from `const PROGMEM char* text;`

---

add constructor to initialize an object.

```
A(const char* _text) {
  text = _text;
}
```

and then

```
A a(PSTR("Hello World!"));
```

---

EDIT:

you could use Arduino's F() macro and __FlashStringHelper type, because it is supported by Serial print and co.

```
class A
{
public:
  A(const __FlashStringHelper* _text) {
    text = _text;
  }
  const __FlashStringHelper* text;
};

void setup()
{
    A a(F("Hello World!"));

    Serial.begin(9600);
    delay(30);
    Serial.println(a.text);
}

void loop()
{
}
```

__FlashStringHelper type is trick to distinguish PROGMEM strings from char arrays in SRAM..

Comment: This is not an answer on my question. How to store strings in flash memory? Strings must be passed to the contructor.

Comment: it is unclear what is what you don't know. I enhanced the answer

Comment: Hum... Your solution won't let use Serial.println. And added user-defined  constructor does not any difference here.

Comment: @zhekaus, yes, your question combined 3 problems. Edgar got them all, but the true solution is to use F macro, not PSTR, if possible. I enhanced the answer